# Problem about two elastic ropes in equilibrium

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

I have an elementary geometric problem that has thus far resisted all efforts from my end.  The problem concerns "elastic ropes" which I model as a sequence of points $\gamma=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($d\geq 2$).  The "rope" has unit tension and is supported on the union of line segments connecting this path:
$$
S(\gamma) := \bigcup_{j=1}^{m-1} \overline{x_jx_{j+1}} \subset\mathbb{R}^d.
$$
The $j$-th segment of the path $\gamma$ points in the direction $\tau_j$,
$$
\tau_j = \frac{x_{j+1}-x_j}{|x_{j+1}-x_j|}.
$$
The rope is at unit tension and exerts a force $f_\gamma$ represented by the measure
$$
f_\gamma = \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} \tau_j (\delta_{x_j} - \delta_{x_{j+1}}).
$$
Here $\delta_x$ is the Dirac delta supported at $x$, and $f_\gamma$ is a vector-valued measure.

Notice that the support of $f_\gamma$ might be a strict subset of $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$, as it is possible for the rope to intersect itself in such a way as to balance the forces at a particular intersection.

> **Question:**
> Let $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ be two ropes satisfying $f_\gamma=f_{\gamma'}$.  Does it follow
> that $S(\gamma)=S(\gamma')$?

As an example, consider a path $\gamma$ with a loop, so $\gamma=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_2, x_5)$.  One can check that the path which traces the loop in the opposite direction,
$\gamma'=(x_1,x_2,x_4,x_3,x_2,x_5)$ has the same forces ($f_\gamma=f_{\gamma'}$), but they share the same support ($S(\gamma)=S(\gamma')$).

By case work I can show that this holds for $m\leq 4$, and I have not found any counterexamples by computer search (but I do not have any sense what an effective algorithm for finding counterexamples would look like anyway...), so I would appreciate any insight whatsoever into this question.  There are several equivalent formulations and non-examples I can provide if there is interest.

Comment: We can reformulate the problem to allow arbitrary rational tensions in each rope by scaling everything by twice the common denominator to get even integer tensions, then finding an Eulerian path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
This is an example of two arrangements with the same $f_\gamma$ and different supports. All angles are $\pi/3$ or $2\pi/3$. In order to make each one be a single rope, we specify that each segment drawn is actually two lengths of rope, and find an Eulerian cycle.

Comment: Thanks!  I like the idea of doubling up the edges on the rope, I hadn't considered that before.