# Can a generic rope exert the same force as a rope with loops?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

This is a spin-off of my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364158/problem-about-two-elastic-ropes-in-equilibrium).  I will take a moment to reintroduce the notation.  The problem concerns elastic "ropes" in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which are modeled as sequences of points $\gamma=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$.  A rope is supported on the union of line segments
$$
S(\gamma) := \bigcup_{j=1}^{m-1} \overline{x_jx_{j+1}} \subset\mathbb{R}^3.
$$
The $j$-th segment of the rope has direction
$$
\tau_j := \frac{x_{j+1} - x_j}{|x_{j+1}-x_j|},
$$
and the force $F_\gamma$ associated to the rope $\gamma$ is described by the vector-valued measure
$$
F_\gamma := \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} \tau_j (\delta_{x_{j+1}} - \delta_{x_j}).
$$

This time I am curious about "generic" ropes $\gamma$.  We say that $\gamma$ is generic if the points $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\}$ are in general position.  That is, the points are all distinct, no three are collinear, and no four are coplanar.  In particular, no two of the line segments $\overline{x_jx_{j+1}}$ and $\overline{x_kx_{k+1}}$ intersect except when $j=k+1$ or vice versa (so there are no loops in $S_\gamma$).

> **Question**:  Suppose that $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are two ropes with the same force, so
> that $F_\gamma = F_{\gamma'}$.   If $\gamma$ is generic, does it follow that
> $\gamma'$ is also generic?

What I believe I can show is that, if $\gamma'$ is not generic, it must have at least three loops.  I would also be curious if there was a reasonable strengthening of the "generic rope" condition that satisfied this conjecture.  So what I am really after is something like the question below.

> **Question'** Is there a set $S$ of "good ropes" that can be described explicitly with the following properties:
>
> - For two ropes $\gamma,\gamma'$ with $\gamma\in S$ and $F_\gamma=F_{\gamma'}$, $\gamma'$ is guaranteed not to have any self-intersections (that is, $S(\gamma')$ has no loops).
> - The set $S$ is "generic" or at least "dense".

For example, I am happy to consider only ropes that do not have any corners with angle $2\pi/3$, if that were to help at all.